# Table with two kinds of rows

Tags: tables

How would I go about making a table that looks like this :

A-------
A1-------
A2-------
B-------
B1-------
B2-------

Where rows A and B have the same columns, A1, A2, B1, B2 have all the same columns, but different from those of A and B.

Finding a common subdivision of columns of the two kinds of rows would be a nightmare.

EDIT : Here's a picture of what I have in mind :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You question is unclear, but you may be looking for `\multicolumn`!

Comment: My understanding of \multicolumn is that you make a cell span several columns. This works well if say the set of columns of rows of type A1 is a subset of the set of columns of rows of type A. That's what I refer to when I talk about a common subdivision of columns.

Comment: Can you give us an image of what you want?  Perhaps created in Excel or a drawing program?

Comment: @JadeSnail: Well, as I said, your question is unclear

Comment: @JadeSnail, with `multicolumn` you can also change coulmn type in selected cell, for example: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` for centering content of this cell ... And as  Christian Hupfer said, your question is unclear. Try to provide a table in which wrote in cell, what should formatting differ from other cell.

Comment: @JadeSnail, the simplest way make your table seems to be  compose it as stack of set of different tables which even tables in stack are shifted for selected amount to the right.

Comment: @Zarko Did I hear **stack**?

Comment: @Zarko Do you mean that I should make two different tables then merge them taking one row from one, then another from the second one etc ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Yes. I'm temporary heavy occupied with some other work, if you not receive before an answer, late evening I will try to write  MWE.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, yes you hear right :-).

Comment: @Jade Snail, meanwhile you receive two answer (unfortunately Christian Hupfer erase his nice answer), so I can enjoy peaceull evening :-).

Comment: @Zarko: or provide another answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here an example of a solution based on `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,  booktabs, tabularx, caption}
\usepackage[table,  svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering\captionsetup{labelfont=sc, skip=6pt}
  \caption{A table}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.67\linewidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Lavender!60}A & B & C \\%
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}\\[-1.1pt]
  \rowcolors{1}{Yellow!10}{Yellow!10}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.67\linewidth}{|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    a & b & c & d & e \\
    \hline
    s & t & u & v & w \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}\\[-1.1pt]%
  \begin{tabularx}{0.67\linewidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \rowcolor{Lavender!60} A & B & C \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}\\[-1.1pt]
  \begin{tabularx}{0.67\linewidth}{|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    a & b & c & d & e \\
    \hline
    s & t & u & v & w \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]